# Exportar matriz a csv en R

Tags: r

Tengo 3 csv con 3050 lineas cada uno, lo que quiero hacer es juntar los 3 y añadirles datos adicionales para luego sacarlo en un nuevo csv.
Pero al exportar la matriz resultante me encuentro con que el formato no es correcto.

El código es este:

```
nombres <- read.csv("C:/Users/CASA/Desktop/nombres.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NA",dec=",")
apellidos1 <- read.csv("C:/Users/CASA/Desktop/apellidos1.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NA",dec=",")
apellidos2 <- read.csv("C:/Users/CASA/Desktop/apellidos2.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NA",dec=",")


total <-3050
clientes<-data.frame(matrix(, nrow=total , ncol=0))

for (ind in 0:total-1){

    clientes$Apellido1<-apellidos1[ind]
      clientes$Apellido2<-apellidos2[ind]
    clientes$Nombre<-nombres[ind]
    clientes$DNI<-generadni()
    clientes$Telf<-sample(600000000:699999999,1)
}
print(clientes)
print("FIN")

#DNI

generadni<-function(){
  valor<-sample(10000000:99999999,1)
  dni<-valor
  valor<-valor/23
  valor<-as.integer(valor)
  valor<-valor*23
  valor<-dni-valor
  #letras<-"TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKEO"
  letras<-c("T","R","W","A","G","M","Y","F","P","D","X","B","N","J","Z","S","Q","V","H","L","C","K","E","O")
  #dni<-as.character(dni)
  #letra<-substr(letras,valor,1)
  letra<-letras[valor]
  resultado<-paste(dni,letra,sep="")
  return(resultado)
}

write.csv2(clientes, "C:/Users/CASA/Desktop/resultado.csv", sep=",")
```

Si ejecuto el script en la consola se ve bien como en el ejemplo:

```
     APELLIDO1       DNI      Telf
1      Aguilar 17139198B 636536106
2       Alonso 17139198B 636536106
3      Álvarez 17139198B 636536106
...
```

Pero cuando abro el CSV lo veo mal, como si la primera columna en vez de ser una cadena de texto fuera c1(numeros del 1 al 108), DNI, teléfono...

Un ejemplo:

```
"";"Apellido1";"DNI";"Telf"
"1";c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,...(to 108)),
```

Comment: Marc, por qué tienes `sep=","` y luego en el ejemplo del csv tienes `;`?

Comment: Marc, se agradecería si muestras un ejemplo de los datos de `clientes`, puedes hacer algo así: `dput(head(clientes))`. y agregar la salida editando tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Analizando las primeras tres lineas del codigo:

```
nombres <- read.csv("C:/Users/CASA/Desktop/nombres.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NA",dec=",")
apellidos1 <- read.csv("C:/Users/CASA/Desktop/apellidos1.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NA",dec=",")
apellidos2 <- read.csv("C:/Users/CASA/Desktop/apellidos2.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NA",dec=",")
```

Entiendo que estos deberian ser data frames y, por el codigo que sigue, parecen contener solo una columna con 3050 elementos.

```
total <-3050
clientes<-data.frame(matrix(, nrow=total , ncol=0))

for (ind in 0:total-1){

    clientes$Apellido1<-apellidos1[ind]
    clientes$Apellido2<-apellidos2[ind]
    clientes$Nombre<-nombres[ind]
    clientes$DNI<-generadni()
    clientes$Telf<-sample(600000000:699999999,1)
}
```

Este loop no tiene sentido.

- El indice `ind` se usa para acceder apellidos y nombres,
  pero no `clientes$Apellido1` (ni los otros)
- Todas las columnas definidas de esta manera terminan valiendo igual a lo que vale el ultimo indice.

Me parece que el codigo deberia ser:

```
nombres <- read.csv("C:/Users/CASA/Desktop/nombres.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NA",dec=",")
apellidos1 <- read.csv("C:/Users/CASA/Desktop/apellidos1.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NA",dec=",")
apellidos2 <- read.csv("C:/Users/CASA/Desktop/apellidos2.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NA",dec=",")

generadni<-function(){
  valor<-sample(10000000:99999999,1)
  dni<-valor
  valor<-valor/23
  valor<-as.integer(valor)
  valor<-valor*23
  valor<-dni-valor
  #letras<-"TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKEO"
  letras<-c("T","R","W","A","G","M","Y","F","P","D","X","B","N","J","Z","S","Q","V","H","L","C","K","E","O")
  #dni<-as.character(dni)
  #letra<-substr(letras,valor,1)
  letra<-letras[valor]
  resultado<-paste(dni,letra,sep="")
  return(resultado)
}

clientes <- data.frame(Nombre = nombres, 
                       Apellido1 = apellidos1, 
                       Apellido2 = apellidos2, 
                       DNI = replicate(length(apellidos1), generadni()),
                       Telf = sample(600000000:699999999, length(apellidos1), replace = T),
                       stringsAsFactors = F)

write.csv2(x = clientes, 
           file = "C:/Users/CASA/Desktop/resultado.csv",
           row.names = F,
           sep = ",",
           quote = F)
```

Me parece que el error en el csv grabado se debe a que guarda los numeros de linea. Esto se evita con la opcion `row.names = F`.